Estimates from low resolution measurements: The weight of a single almond
Christmas will be here before we know it, so we've started honing our christmas cookie baking skills. Today it was a madeleine variety, so almonds were involved. While weighing up the almonds the question about what a single almond weighs arose.
Our kitchen scale only has a resolution of one gram, and a single almond didn't even register. The known solution is of course to weigh a bunch at once, and then divide the total weight by the number of almonds, giving the mean weight per almond in that sample.
In most situations this is probably good enough, but it's only a point estimate, and I wondered if it was possible to do better.
What I did:
55 almonds were divided into equally sized groups, using three different group sizes; 11,  6 and 18. 55 isn't divisible by 6 or 18, so a single almond was left out in those cases.
The results were:
options(digits=3)

l <- list(
  n11=c(14, 14, 13, 14, 13),
  n6 =c(6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7),
  n18=c(20, 21, 19))

n <- c(11, 6, 18)

est <- mapply(function(x, y) mean(x/y), l, n)
std <- mapply(function(x, y) sd(x/y)*sqrt(y), l, n)

cbind(est, std)
#      est   std
# n11 1.24 0.165
# n6  1.07 0.215
# n18 1.11 0.236

My question is: Is it possible to use these measurements to make an estimate with error margins? Is there something I could change in my methodology to improve my estimate, keeping in mind the limitations (55 almonds in total and a scale with one gram resolution)?

I had to get a new batch of 55 almonds, but I did do as I think Peter suggested. I resampled into five groups à 11, a total of eight times, and weighed them.
I then estimate the mean and standard deviation as best as I can, run a simulation with those values, estimate the mean and standard deviation again, and compare with the values I got from my original eight resamples. The values line up very well. Does this mean that, if we assume a normal distribution and that the scale simply rounds to the nearest whole gram, that my best estimate for the mean and standard deviation of the big bag of almonds I sampled 55 from is, respectively 0.998 and 0.247?
n11r <- cbind(c(12, 12, 11, 10, 11),
              c(11, 11, 11, 10, 11),
              c(11, 11, 11, 12, 10),
              c(10, 10, 10, 13, 11),
              c(10, 12, 12, 10, 10),
              c(10, 11, 12, 12, 10),
              c(11, 11, 12, 11, 10),
              c(11, 11, 12, 11, 11))

mean(apply(n11r, 2, function(x) mean(x/11)))
# [1] 0.998
mean(apply(n11r, 2, function(x) sd(x/11)*sqrt(11)))
# [1] 0.247

set.seed(1)
rr <- replicate(1e4, {
    round(rowSums(matrix(rnorm(55, 0.998, 0.247), nrow=5)))
})

mean(apply(rr, 2, function(x) mean(x/11)))
# [1] 0.998
mean(apply(rr, 2, function(x) sd(x/11)*sqrt(11)))
# [1] 0.245


Why 55 exactly? Also, your plan seems to entangle the variation in the weight of the almonds and measurement error in your scale. I would make 5 piles of 11 almonds each and weight each pile several times.

@PeterFlom: 55 because that's how many was left in the bag. Are you proposing I should randomly distribute the almonds into 5 equal piles a number of times? Can I get an estimate of the variability of individual almond weights from this?

I would also weigh the same group of almonds multiple times.

You have 2 sources of variability (uncertainty) affecting your measurements; the variability of the weight between almonds, and the measurement uncertainty of your scale ($\pm 0.5g$).
As the OP mentions, the "known solution", is to weigh multiple almonds, to go above the resolution limit of the scale. You maximize this when you weigh all 55 almonds together. But you can only do 1 such measurement? So you could repeat the measurements multiple times? But that will then just give you an estimate of the scale resolution, because you have repeated measures of a single "unit" (the bunch of 55 almonds). But the OP wants to know the variability of the weight of almonds? So any method with repeated measures will not give us what we want...
What can we do. Well, the next best thing is to measure 54 almonds. That reduces the measurement uncertainty to $\pm \frac {0.5} {54} \approx 0.0093g$. Let's call it $\pm .01g$: quite small.
Now you can (theoretically) create 55 such samples with 54 almonds. Basically you just exclude a single almond at a time. This is nothing else than the "Leave-one-out" method applied to this scenario; and it can be shown that it is almost unbiased.
We have now made the measurements errors so small that the mean and variance obtained from the 55 measurements reflect the mean and variance of the almond's weight, as best we can given the instrument (scale).
Now, there are some practical problems here; you need to uniquely identify each of your 55 almonds; not too practical (you could label each with a Sharpie, but the added weight of the ink on 54 almonds would skew the results). But you may be able to still generate 10-20 such samples, by arranging almonds on your scale in a way which ensures that all your 10-20 54-sized subsamples are unique.
Another issue would be that manipulating the almonds again and again, could lead to some damage to the almonds (breakage, chips, etc...) which could affect their weight.
But since (I am pretty sure) this is a hypothetical scenario, we can gloss over these practical problems.

This approach overlooks the need to analyze measurement error into an iid error term and a term due to coarse resolution (rounding) of the result.  When the resolution is poorer than the measurement error and greater than the spread of almond weights, you might always get the very same weight for those groups of 54 almonds, thereby obtaining a biased estimate of the measurement error.

This is still the "best" method given the OP's circumstances. Ssay that the weight of 54 almonds is 53.751g, and that the variability among almonds is so small, that for all measurements read 54g. The estimate will be 1g/almond +/-.01g. The true weight would be .995g. Certainly not a bias I would worry much about. And if there is any measurable variability in almond weights, the bias will be even less. Fwiw, depending on the source, the weight of an almond is between 1g and 1.5g. And if one is bothered by 54 identical measurements, then take 2 (or 3?) out until variability is meqasurable.

One this site, which is not a cooking site, we ought to take "almonds" as a more general metaphor for this kind of statistical problem.

Of course; see the last sentence in my answer...
